# how to get mobile date and time in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I need to get device date and time using DateField.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same thing has in Java [Date()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/java/util/Date.html)